# where can i find java element filters dialog?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Where is the java element filters dialog in eclipse?

I can't find it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you explain more details? About what elements you talking?

Comment: I need to hint package empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In package explorer tab -> view menu (down arrow icon) -> customize views.

Then you can select radio button to show the empty package.

Answer (score 2):

In STS v3.1, if you are viewing the Java perspective, you can see this in the Package Explorer view:

[image: screenshot of Java perspective's Package Explorer view, view menu]

Then you can manipulate the "view" by checking (or unchecking) those elements that you with to filter (or show) like this:

[image: screenshot of Java Element Filters]

Hope that helps.